# How to create where condition from dictionary of Key and value pairs? in C# Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, expression, func

How to create a where condition from the dictionary of key and value pairs?
I have a dictionary that contains values for where conditions.

```
var pkkeys = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  { "pkkey1", "value1" },
  { "pkkey2", "value2" },
  { "pkkey3", "value4" }
}
```

I need to create something like this:

```
db.GetTable<SomeTable>()
  .Where(t => (t.code == "pkkey1" && t.value == "value1") 
              || (t.code == "pkkey2" && t.value == "value2")
              || (t.code == "pkkey3" && t.value == "value3"));
```

Thanks.

I tried the below code:

```
Expression<Func<SomeDictionary, bool>> e = (x) => false;

foreach (var dictKeyValue in dictKeyValues)
{
    e.Or((t) => dictKeyValue.Code == t.Code && dictKeyValue.Value == t.Value);
}

var expe = tbl => this.dbContext.Set<SomeTable>()
                      .Any(e.Compile());
```

Comment: I believe that you should do `e = e.Or(...)`, i.e. use what's returned by the method.

Answer (score 1):

Expression first parameter type should be `SomeTable`.

I assumpution SomeTable like this:

```
public class SomeTable 
{
   public string Code { get; set;}
   
   public string Value { get; set;}

}
```

Expression:

```
Expression<Func<SomeTable, bool>> e = (x) => 
                     dict.Any(a => a.Key == x.Code && a.Value == x.Value);

var result = this.dbContext.Set<SomeTable>()
                      .Where(e.Compile());
```